# Why is the logic not working in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my apps navbar, I have the following code:
*apps/views/layout/application.html.erb:*

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%if current_user.userinfo(&:info_complete) %>
                <li><%= link_to "My profile", userinfo_path(current_user.userinfo.id) %></li> 
            <% elsif current_user.employer(&:info_complete)%>
                <li><%= link_to "My profile", employer_path(current_user.employer.id) %></li>     
            <%else%>  
                <li><%= link_to "Complete Profile", application_studoremp_path %></li>          
            <%end%>  
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>       
        <% else %>  
            <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>                  
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

When a user signs up, they will be directed to a page to choose if they want to continue as an employer or student, then they will be directed to a page to fill out userinfo if they choose student, or fill out the employer info if they choose employer. So between signing up and filling out one of the forms, the user will not have "userinfo.id" OR "employer.id". That's why I redirect them to "application_studoremp_path". But the app throws an error saying userinfo.id is not found. Obviously it's not found because it's not created yet, that's why there is an "else" part. Why is the logic not working? :info_complete is a function in both the userinfo model and the employer model checking if the information has been filled out. Everything works fine if the user is already existing (If the userinfo.id or employer.id already exists).
This is the error:
[image]

My userinfo.rb model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is in your function `info_complete` that is not returning the right value.

I would suggest you try some test on it, and I guess that when you wanna reference a variable from your model, you should use "`:`", like this:

```
def info_complete
  :name? && :age? 
end
```

Comment: Hey Pedro, my model is right because it works in other places. It doesn't work only as soon as the user signs in. My questions is, since the info_complete returns not true on either Userinfo OR Employer, why doesn't the code jump straight to the  <li><%= link_to "Complete Profile", application_studoremp_path %></li>  line?

Comment: I think it's not jumping because you function is returning true (when should be false), that is why. The throwing error is showing that rails is trying to access your first statement. Try to change the position of the statement userinfo and employer, put employer first.

Comment: Did you try my first suggestion? Use ":"

Answer (score 0):

You are using method incorrectly.
The notation `method(&:other)` is a shorthand for `method {|i| i.other}`. What is happening here is prefix `&` is the same as calling `to_proc` method on object prefixed.

Now, `userinfo` is a getter, and you can pass it a block (of course) but it will be ignored, it is just a getter.

So all you actually do is check whether `userinfo` is not `nil` (or `false`). You also can tell, because `(&:info_complete)` does not even fire a `NoMethodError` (and it should, because there is no `info_complete`, there is `info_complete?`).

What you should do is to just use `userinfo.info_complete?` And if you are concerned `user_info` could be nil, do it with safe navigation operator: `userinfo&.info_complete?`

Further reading: [Ampersand operator](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby)
[Safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)